# What are the contours lines on the Cook's list vs Leverage h_ii / (1-h_ii) plot?

Tags: regression

According to the documentation, plot #6 of plot.lm in R: 
"In the Cook's distance vs leverage/(1-leverage) plot, contours of standardized residuals that are equal in magnitude are lines through the origin. The contour lines are labeled with the magnitudes."

What exactly are these dotted lines?
[image]

Source: 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot.lm

Answer (score 1):

Cook's distance is large if either the observation has a large residual or if it exerts a high leverage on the model. As you can see from the plot something in the top left hand corner has a high residual (2.5) but not necessarily a large leverage. In the bottom right hand corner the converse is true.